# Media-Query min-width not working below specified min-width

Tags: html, css

I am using a media query with a specified min-width of 480px. The media query works at 480px but when I scale the screen below 480px the media query ceases to work. I am not sure why this is happening. I thought the purpose of using a min-width media query was so that the style rules would take effect in all sizes below the specified min-width.

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
   .preview-title{
     font-size: 28px;
   }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

  .preview-title{
   font-size: 38px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`min-width` represents the minimum width at which the query will occur. You're looking for `max-width`.

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
   .preview-title{
     font-size: 28px;
   }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {

  .preview-title{
   font-size: 38px;
  }
}
```